# c# metro style apps referencing javascript metro style apps

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I am building a metro style app using c#, but in the middle I realized that I have to do something with javascript. now I am confused what to do? do I have to make the entire app using javascript and html5 or there is a way where I can reference the c# metro style app to the required js metro style app, and reference it back to my c# metro style proj later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be your solution: [Creating an HTML Metro style app that references C# and C++ code](http://blendinsider.com/technical/creating-an-html-metro-style-app-that-references-c-and-c-code-2012-04-13/)

Check the section `Configure C# projects to generate WinMD files` and `Set up project references` section in the reference link. You need to set the c# project output the WinMD (Windows Meta Data). A hybrid project may solve your problem.

Hope this help you that you are trying to implement..

Comment: i actually want to use js part in the middle of the app, how is it possible if I reference my c# to js project?

Comment: yes.. you set the check this reference link.. you can use set the output type of the c# project and then you can reference c# project in js project..